# Reactjs: change A tags to <Link> tags, from list group Bootstrap 4

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using Reactjs and I am trying to use this list group from Bootstrap 4. However, when I change the A tags to `<Link>` the code does not work anymore, and will not display anything. What is the best way to have it rendered in React using `<Link>`?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

e.g.
`<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"...` into `<Link className="list-group-item... >`

Comment: What is `Link`? From where it came from? If you don't see anything you probably have an error on your log. Please share it

Comment: `<Link>` is from react-router-dom, I believe I cannot use a tags in create-react-app. Also, I don't have any errors on my log.

Comment: @this-keyword <Link /> is use for navigating component and if you want to use put like <Link to="/list-home" /> for every link with different href.

Comment: @this-keyword you need to install react router dom for using routing

Comment: If you want to use `Bootstrap` so use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/list-group/)

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I have already tried your suggestion awhile back but it's still not working. `<Link
     className="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"
     id="list-home-list"
     data-toggle="list"
     to="/list-home"
     role="tab"
     aria-controls="home"
    >
     Home
    </Link>` I have also installed react-router-dom prior to importing it.

Comment: @this-keyword what problem are you facing?

Comment: @Pedram I may need to use React Bootstrap instead if `<Link>` is currently not supported in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar my problem is I can't have the list group to display if I remove the a tags and replace them with the `<Link>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with this code, and after removing the `data-toggle="list"` the code worked with the `<Link>` tags!